# Python - ModuleNotFoundError thrown when calling a function that imports another module in the same directory

Tags: python

I have the following Python file structure.

```
-- main.py

-- scripts/

        -- __init__.py
        -- helper_functions.py
        -- mytest.py
```

`mytest.py` has the following function.

```
def test():
    print("test")
```

`helper_functions.py` imports the mytest module and use the test function as

```
import mytest

def hello():
    mytest.test()
if __name__=="__main__":
    mytest.test()
```

`__init__.py` imports the hello function from helper_functions.py module so that the main.py outside the scripts folder can directly use the hello function.

```
from scripts.helper_functions import hello
```

`main.py` tries to call the hello function directly:

```
from scripts import hello

if __name__=="__main__":
    hello()
```

When I tried to run `main.py`, the following error was thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scripts import hello
  File "\scripts\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scripts.helper_functions import hello
  File "\scripts\helper_functions.py", line 8, in <module>
    import mytest
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mytest'
```

It seems the mytest module couldn't be imported into helper_functions.py. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Hint: when you wrote `from scripts.helper_functions import hello`, why did you **not** write `from helper_functions import hello`? Would you expect that to also work? Where the code says `import mytest`, which folder do you expect Python to check for the `mytest.py` file, and **why** do you expect it to check there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main.py and mytest.py are not in the same directory.
To solve the error either put main.py in the same directory as mytest.py or replace `import mytest` with `from scripts import mytest` in helper_functions file. Then main.py will be able to access mytest.py. Modified helper_functions.py:

```
try:
    import mytest
    
except:
    from scripts import mytest

def hello():
    mytest.test()
if __name__=="__main__":
    mytest.test()
```

The `try` and `except` block checks if mytest.py is in the same directory as the file that calls it. If it is in the same directory, then, `import mytest` is used. Otherwise `from scripts import mytest` is used.

Comment: Thanks. This works for running the main.py script. However, when I tried to run "python helper_functions.py" directly, the following error was thrown: `from scripts import mytest
ImportError: cannot import name 'mytest' from 'scripts' (unknown location)`

Answer (score 2):

In `helperfunctions.py` replace your code:

```py
import mytest

def hello():
    mytest.test()
if __name__=="__main__":
    mytest.test()
```

As following:

```py
from scripts import mytest

def hello():
    mytest.test()
if __name__=="__main__":
    mytest.test()
```